# Clicking an element within an iframe (automating using Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

How do I click a web element within this iframe?
I do not have a name, ID and I am getting a `null pointer exception` on returning the number of iframes.
I am looking to click the 'Set up Index patterns' link

I tried using the class name iframe-continer and it worked but the page returned was blank. I am not sure what is going wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
<app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="5.2.11">
<router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
<admin-console class="ng-star-inserted" _nghost-c1="">
<div class="dashboard-shell-container" _ngcontent-c1="">
<mat-menu class="" _ngcontent-c1=""></mat-menu>
<mat-tab-group class="mat-tab-group mat-primary" _ngcontent-c1="" style="padding-top: 63px;">
<mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header mat-tab-header-pagination-controls-enabled">
<div class="mat-tab-body-wrapper">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-0" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-14 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-0">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-1" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-15 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-1">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-2" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-16 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-2">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-3" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-17 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-3">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-4" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-18 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-4">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-5" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-19 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-5">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-6" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-20 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-6">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-7" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-21 ng-star-inserted mat-tab-body-active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-7">
<div class="mat-tab-body-content ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab" style="transform: none;">
<app-aca-component-loader class="ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c7="" style="">
<div class="app-kibana ng-star-inserted" _nghost-c26="">
<br _ngcontent-c26="">
<button class="calendar-icon mat-fab mat-accent" _ngcontent-c26="" mat-fab="">
<br _ngcontent-c26="">
<br _ngcontent-c26="">
<div _ngcontent-c26="">
<iframe class="iframe-continer" _ngcontent-c26="" src="/kibana-dashboard/" frameborder="0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body id="kibana-body" kbn-chrome="">
<div class="content" chrome-context="" data-test-subj="kibanaChrome">
<nav class="global-nav is-global-nav-open" ng-class="{'is-global-nav-open': isGlobalNavOpen}" ng-show="isVisible" chrome="chrome" data-test-subj="globalNav" is-visible="chrome.getVisible()" logo-brand="chrome.getBrand('logo')" small-logo-brand="chrome.getBrand('smallLogo')" app-title="chrome.getAppTitle()" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="app-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'hidden-chrome': !chrome.getVisible() }">
<div class="app-wrapper-panel">
<div class="toaster-container" list="notifList">
<div class="loadingIndicator ng-hide" ng-show="chrome.httpActive.length" data-test-subj="globalLoadingIndicator" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="application tab-home" ng-class="'tab-' + chrome.getFirstPathSegment() + ' ' + chrome.getApplicationClasses()" ng-view="" ng-controller="chrome.$$rootControllerConstruct as kibana">
<home-app add-base-path="addBasePath" directories="directories">
<div class="euiPage home">
<div class="euiFlexGroup euiFlexGroup--gutterLarge euiFlexGroup--alignItemsFlexEnd euiFlexGroup--justifyContentSpaceBetween euiFlexGroup--responsive">
<div class="euiFlexItem">
<div class="euiFlexItem euiFlexItem--flexGrowZero">
<span class="euiTextColor euiTextColor--subdued">
<div class="euiSpacer euiSpacer--s"></div>
<a class="euiButton euiButton--primary euiButton--small" href="#/management/kibana/index">
<span class="euiButton__content">Set up index patterns</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="euiSpacer euiSpacer--l"></div>
<div class="kuiVerticalRhythm">
<div class="euiSpacer euiSpacer--l"></div>
<div class="euiFlexGroup euiFlexGroup--gutterLarge euiFlexGroup--responsive kuiVerticalRhythm">
<div class="euiSpacer euiSpacer--l"></div>
<div class="euiFlexGroup euiFlexGroup--gutterLarge euiFlexGroup--justifyContentCenter euiFlexGroup--responsive">
</div>
</home-app>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
</app-aca-component-loader>
</div>
</mat-tab-body>
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-8" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-22 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-8">
<mat-tab-body id="mat-tab-content-0-9" class="mat-tab-body ng-tns-c9-23 ng-star-inserted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mat-tab-label-0-9">
</div>
</mat-tab-group>
</admin-console>
</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can find an element by class name or by Tag name.

Comment: Please, share your HTML so we can help you more easily.

Comment: how do I share it? is there an attachment option here? (new here)

Comment: You can edit your original post and add code.

Answer (score 0):

We can switch over the elements in frames using 3 ways.

- By Index
- By Name or Id
- By Web Element

**Switch to the frame by index:**

Index is one of the attributes for the Iframe through which we can switch to it.

Index of the iframe starts with '0'.

Suppose if there are 100 frames in page, we can switch to the iframe by using index.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

**Another Solution:**

> driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("iframe-continer")))
>   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Set up index patterns')]")).click();

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, Please look at my HTML posted above. I want to click 'Set up index patterns'

Comment: @Premi: is it possible to share your url?

Comment: I copied the HTML source in my post. will that do?

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("iframe-continer"))) driver.findElement(By.className("euiButton__content")).click()

Comment: driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Set up index patterns')]")).click();

Comment: Yes I did. I have a frame with no contents

Comment: Can you share your URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking on an element inside of an iframe, you first need to switch to iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("iframe-continer"))).
```

And then

```
driver.findElement(By.className("euiButton__content")).click()
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='#/management/kibana/index']")).click()
```

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("iframe.continer")));
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='kibana-body']/div/div/div/div[3]/home-app/div/div[1]/div[2]/a/span")).click();                            org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"iframe.continer"}

Comment: Try "iframe-container" instead of "iframe.container".

Comment: facepalm... thanks! It switched and my page was all blank. Does this mean I am looking for the element in the wrong frame? I will copy the HTML page here

Comment: Try driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='#/management/kibana/index']")).click(). Do you still get the NoSuchElementException?

Comment: Yes - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href='#/management/kibana/index']"}

Comment: Is this what you want me to do?driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("iframe-continer")));
driver.findElement(By.className("euiButton__content")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='#/management/kibana/index']")).click();

Comment: This is not working. I am redirected to some frame without any contents in it.

Comment: Well, what is at "#/management/kibana/index" when you click on it manually?

Comment: Okay, in the firefox browser launched through the test, there is the blank frame. In the firefox browser launched outside of the test, I have the page I need